# How can I use material graphic elements in a html static page?

Tags: html, material-ui

I'm developing a static website which will be saved in CDs and USB sticks. It is a manual of a product.

I would to use a graphic framework as onsen ui, but I like material ui more.

I want to use only material ui to create html elements (cards, listtiles, etc...), and all the website will work offline.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: What you need? Icon resource?

Comment: Icons and material widgets. If in flutter I write Card(), in html I would to write <card> or similar to get the same graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out [Materialize CSS](https://materializecss.com/). It is CSS + JavaScript library based on Material UI created by Google. It has lots of per-build components Buttons, Badges, Cards, Navbar, Pagination, Floating Action Button. Along with that many per-build CSS classes are provided which you can use to follow Material standards without going into details. Furthermore, you can also visit [JavaTpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/materialize-css-tutorial) which also provides good tutorials on Materialize CSS.

Materialize CSS provides icons as CSS but if you want to download Material Icons as images(raster PNGs or vector SVGs) visit [Material.IO](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=accessibility&style=sharp)

Comment: How can I define theme colors and fonts in materialize?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at https://material.io/develop/web you'll see that [Material Components Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/) is there.

> Material Components for the web is the successor to Material Design
> Lite. In addition to implementing the Material Design guidelines, it
> provides more flexible theming customization, not only in terms of
> color, but also typography, shape, states, and more. It is also
> specifically architected for adaptability to various major web
> frameworks.